# Boundedness of weakly convergent sequence in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working through Rudin's Functional Analysis.  I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem.

The problem states:  $X$ is a Banach space.  $\{x_n\}$ is a weakly convergent sequence in $X$, then $\{\|x_n\|\}$ is bounded.

My instinct is to assume an unbounded sequence and try to prove that any tail gets separated by the functionals that define a weakly open set.  The problem is that you might need a different functional to separate each large point in the tail, but we can only build neighborhoods out of finitely many functionals.

So maybe I need a different approach.  The strangest part to me is that I think the completeness of $X$ is needed; I'm not sure about the dual space of $L^\infty([0,1])$, but I think that $\{2^n\cdot\bf1_{[1/n,1/n]}\}$ is unbounded but converges weakly to the zero function.  With other function spaces, though, you need to fatten the functions up and you seem to run of out space...

Is any of my logic wrong??

Comment: Do you have the uniform boundedness principle at your disposal?

Comment: @cauchyproblem The book hasn't covered it, but it assumes knowledge of a lot of outside theorems.

Comment: @Gaffney The uniform boundedness principle (Banach-Steinhaus) is in Chapter 2. Weak topology is in Chapter 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, $\{x_n\}$ is an equicontinuous class of linear functionals on $X^*$. Hence $\{\|x_n\|\}$ is bounded.

Comment: That's it  Thanks!